# rails associations :autosave doesn't seem to working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I made a real basic github project [here](https://github.com/robmathews/posts) that demonstrates the issue. Basically, when I create a new comment, it is saved as expected; when I update an existing comment, it isn't saved. However, that isn't what the docs for `:autosave => true` say ... they say the opposite. Here's the code:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, 
           :autosave => true, 
           :inverse_of => :post,
           :dependent => :destroy

  def comment=(val)
    obj=comments.find_or_initialize_by(:posted_at=>Date.today)
    obj.text=val
  end
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post, :inverse_of=>:comments
end
```

Now in the console, I test:

```
p=Post.create(:name=>'How to groom your unicorn')
p.comment="That's cool!"
p.save!
p.comments # returns value as expected. Now we try the update case ... 

p.comment="But how to you polish the rainbow?"
p.save!
p.comments # oops ... it wasn't updated
```

Why not? What am I missing?

Note if you don't use "find_or_initialize", it works as ActiveRecord respects the association cache - otherwise it reloads the comments too often, throwing out the change. ie, this implementation works

```
def comment=(val)
  obj=comments.detect {|obj| obj.posted_at==Date.today}
  obj = comments.build(:posted_at=>Date.today) if(obj.nil?)
  obj.text=val
end
```

But of course, I don't want to walk through the collection in memory if I could just do it with the database. Plus, it seems inconsistent that it works with new object but not an existing object.

Comment: In your first example, have you tried calling the last line as `p.comment.reload` ?

Comment: Not important, as in fact activerecord decides to reload the entire collection no matter what you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another option.  You can explicitly add the record returned by `find_or_initialize_by` to the collection if it is not a new record.

```
def comment=(val)
  obj=comments.find_or_initialize_by(:posted_at=>Date.today)
  unless obj.new_record?
    association(:comments).add_to_target(obj) 
  end
  obj.text=val
end
```

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know about association() option before.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can make this work.  When you use find_or_initialize_by it looks like the collection is not used - just the scoping.  So you are getting back a different object.

If you change your method:

```
  def comment=(val)
    obj = comments.find_or_initialize_by(:posted_at => Date.today)
    obj.text = val
    puts "obj.object_id: #{obj.object_id} (#{obj.text})"
    puts "comments[0].object_id: #{comments[0].object_id} (#{comments[0].text})"
    obj.text
  end
```

You'll see this:

```
p.comment="But how to you polish the rainbow?"
obj.object_id: 70287116773300 (But how to you polish the rainbow?)
comments[0].object_id: 70287100595240 (That's cool!)
```

So the comment from find_or_initialize_by is not in the collection, it outside of it.  If you want this to work, I think you need to use detect and build as you have in the question:

```
  def comment=(val)
    obj = comments.detect {|c| c.posted_at == Date.today } || comments.build(:posted_at => Date.today)
    obj.text = val
  end
```

Comment: I think you are right. Looks like what I really want is for the collection to have a "partially loaded" state, such that when Rails tries to load the collection in, it notices that it already has some objects in memory, and then  merges those objects with the objects loaded from the database, rather than simply throwing the objects in memory out.

Answer (score 0):

John Naegle is right.   But you can still do what you want without using `detect`.  Since you are updating only today's comment you can order the association by `posted_date` and simply access the first member of the `comments` collection to updated it.  Rails will autosave for you from there:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, ->{order "posted_at DESC"}, :autosave=>true,     :inverse_of=>:post,:dependent=>:destroy

  def comment=(val)
    if comments.empty? || comments[0].posted_at != Date.today
      comments.build(:posted_at=>Date.today, :text => val)
    else
      comments[0].text=val
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: if comments.empty? What about if you posted yesterday, then come back today? Looks like it updates yesterday's comment, instead of creating a new record.

Comment: true.  my bad.  you can add a check to see if first comment isn't from today:  `if comments.empty? || comments[0].posted_at != Date.today`

Comment: The line "comments[0]" causes the entire collection to be loaded into memory, so it's the same effect as the detect - all the objects are loaded - although you do get to skip the in-memory search. So it's better, but not much better from a performance point of view. And I still have to write the conditional "if", which was part of what we were trying to avoid with the using "find_or_initialize_by". Thanks, though - it's a clever idea.